# Using crossfilter, is it possible to destroy / remove it once its be instantiated?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

Im referring square crossfilter plugin for javascript

https://github.com/square/crossfilter

In my app, users are be able to select specific date ranges and each time the date is changed, an ajax request creates a json object which is fed into crossfilter.

I want to be able to remove the existing crossfilter (objects on screen as well as events) and start a new with the  newly created json object.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, you should be able to undo a filter either by applying

```
.filter(null)
```

or

```
.filterAll()
```

to your object.

However, I have found this does not necessarily work, so perhaps the better thing to do would be to apply a fresh filter to a new crossfilter object.

If you can provide some code for better context that would be helpful.

Comment: I think what he was after (Or at least what I am after now) is to actually remove records from the crossfilter dataset, not just remove the filters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the filters on *all* dimensions derived from the crossfilter to reset it.
For example, if you have applied the following filters

```
payments_by_quantity.filter([1, Infinity]);
payments_by_total.filter(90);
payments_by_tip.filter(0);
payments_by_type.filter("tab");
```

you need to reset each single one to return to the original state:

```
payments_by_quantity.filter(null);
payments_by_total.filter(null);
payments_by_tip.filter(null);
payments_by_type.filter(null);
```

This makes sense, as it allows you to selectively activate/deactivate filters on the dimensions you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(crossFilter.size() > 0) {
     // Need to apply filter to all first
     dc.filterAll(); 
     // Then call remove
     crossFilter.remove();
 }
```